# Can't create Snapshots, how to fallback from Swift to Cinder

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift, openstack-cinder, openstack-glance

I'm managing an installation of OpenStack Juno (deployed with Mirantis 6.0) working with two nodes, one controller and one compute. We're doing some testing and for some reason (our IT team thinks is something related to HAproxy) Swift stopped working.

At the moment, almost everything works but can't create images or snapshots from instances. I can create snapshots from volumes and the other way around. The difference, I think, is the upload of the image, Glance fails to use Cinder to upload the newly created image.

I've been tasket with either repair Swift, or fallback to use Cinder as storage system. The first would be the best sollution but I have no idea how to start.

I'm pretty new to all this and I'm sorry I can't provide more details, I've started working with OpenStack a few weeks ago and still haven't got enough experience to troubleshot this problem myself.

All I could find on the logs are references to "Failed to upload..." like this one in /var/log/glance/api.log

```
    2015-12-16 12:29:47.604 6182 ERROR glance.api.v1.upload_utils [-] Failed to upload image 1856c024-d75a-49e3-a6a9-dc3d7b15e8cc
2015-12-16 12:29:47.604 6182 TRACE glance.api.v1.upload_utils     raise NotImplementedError
2015-12-16 12:29:47.604 6182 TRACE glance.api.v1.upload_utils NotImplementedError
2015-12-16 12:32:22.444 6198 ERROR glance.api.v2.image_data [-] Failed to upload image data due to internal error
2015-12-16 12:32:22.444 6198 TRACE glance.api.v2.image_data     self.notifier.error('image.upload', msg)
    self.notifier.error('image.upload', msg)
2015-12-16 12:39:08.768 6182 ERROR glance.api.v2.image_data [-] Failed to upload image data due to internal error
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by trial and error, it all comes down to glance-api.conf and I needed to add/modify these settings:

```
default_store = cinder

stores = glance.store.filesystem.Store,
         glance.store.http.Store,
         glance.store.cinder.Store,
         glance.store.swift.Store,

filesystem_store_datadir = /var/lib/glance/images/
```